# rs.next() is returning false in while statement

Tags: java, sql, resultset

So, I'm trying to extract msgID and msgStatus values from database for each reference Id(*variable msgRefList*) stored in the list object and I'm trying to store these extracted values in String objects for further processing. But rs.next() method is returning false and hence it is not going into the while loop where the assignment statements are. I checked in database with the query that i'm using in the code and it shows one record in the result, but still rs.next() is returning false. Screenshot attached with the database results.

Below is the actual code that i'm using

```
List<String> msgRefList = listofRefrnceValues:

try {
    Connection connect = connectToDB(ENV);

    for(String reference: msgRefList){

            String query="select ID, MSG_STS from TABLE where INSTR_ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1,reference);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs!=null){

               while(rs.next()) {

                    P_MID = rs.getString("P_MID");
                    P_MSG_STS = rs.getString("P_MSG_STS");
               }

            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: Database Result]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And also please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Is your table name is _TABLE_ ? Show database table content.

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved keyword. try to use `\`TABLE\``

Comment: update the original post with more information. @Lino

Comment: `executeQuery` will **never** return `null`, so your null-check is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Your table name as well as your column names are wrong. It is **MINF** and not **TABLE** .

Comment: I have corrected them all but still it is not going into the while loop.

                String query="select P_MID, P_MSG_STS from MINF where P_INSTR_ID = ?";
                PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.setString(1,reference);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                if(rs!=null){
    
                    while(rs.next()) {
    
                        P_MID = rs.getString("P_MID");
                        P_MSG_STS = rs.getString("P_MSG_STS");
                    }
    
                }

Comment: Everything is incorrect in the query. What do you expect ? At least do some basic level check before posting the question.

Comment: @user10005574 you have a lot of typos in your code, see my answer to see what to change

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your SQL-Query-String in java. Instead of `TABLE` you probably meant `MINF` (your real table) also all of your properties don't have the prefix `P_` and `ID` is probably `MID`. So change:

```
String query="select ID, MSG_STS from TABLE where INSTR_ID = ?";
```

To:

```
String query="select P_MID, P_MSG_STS from MINF where P_INSTR_ID = ?";
```

And you'll be fine.